# Is it safe to pipe the output of several parallel processes to one file using >>?

Tags: unix, concurrency, parallel-processing, pipe

I'm scraping data from the web, and I have several processes of my scraper running in parallel.

I want the output of each of these processes to end up in the same file.  As long as lines of text remain intact and don't get mixed up with each other, the order of the lines does not matter.  In UNIX, can I just pipe the output of each process to the same file using the >> operator?

Comment: *InRe: Close votes.* The way I see it "Is operation Foo safe for concurrent use in language Bar?" is a programming questions every time. In this case Foo is piping input to the std[in,err] and Bar is some unix shell. Gotta say I think it should stay.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No. It is not guaranteed that lines will remain intact. They can become intermingled.

From searching based on liori's answer I found [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/write):

> Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe. Writes of greater than {PIPE_BUF} bytes may have data interleaved, on arbitrary boundaries, with writes by other processes, whether or not the O_NONBLOCK flag of the file status flags is set.

So lines longer than {PIPE_BUF} bytes are not guaranteed to remain intact.

Comment: Just to make it clear -- this case is for pipes only, including named pipes (aka FIFO files). It does not apply to other types of files, where the situation is likely much less guaranteed not to have intermingled writes.

Comment: Does this apply to normal redirection with `>`? I guess that at the low level the shell would open the file differently (open for append and not open for write) so maybe the results are different

Answer (score 16):

One possibly interesting thing you could do is use gnu parallel: http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/ For example if you you were spidering the sites:

```
stackoverflow.com, stackexchange.com, fogcreek.com
```

you could do something like this

```
(echo stackoverflow.com; echo stackexchange.com; echo fogcreek.com) | parallel -k your_spider_script
```

and the output is buffered by parallel and because of the -k option returned to you in the order of the site list above. A real example (basically copied from the 2nd parallel screencast):

```
 ~ $ (echo stackoverflow.com; echo stackexchange.com; echo fogcreek.com) | parallel -k ping -c 1 {}


PING stackoverflow.com (64.34.119.12): 56 data bytes

--- stackoverflow.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
PING stackexchange.com (64.34.119.12): 56 data bytes

--- stackexchange.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
PING fogcreek.com (64.34.80.170): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 64.34.80.170: icmp_seq=0 ttl=250 time=23.961 ms

--- fogcreek.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 23.961/23.961/23.961/0.000 ms
```

Anyway, ymmv

Answer (score 8):

Generally, no.

On Linux this might be possible, as long as two conditions are met: each line is written in a one operation, and the line is no longer than PIPE_SIZE (usually the same as PAGE_SIZE, usually 4096). But... I wouldn't count on that; this behaviour might change.

It is better to use some kind of real logging mechanism, like syslog.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely no, I had a log-management script where I assumed this worked, and it did work, until I moved it to an under-load production server. Not a good day... But basically you end up with sometimes completely mixed up lines.

If I'm trying to capture from multiple sources, it is much simpler (and easier to debug) having a multiple-file 'paper trails' and if I need an over-all log file, concatenate based on timestamp (you are using time-stamps, right?) or as liori said, syslog.

Answer (score 4):

Use temporary files and concatenate them together. It's the only safe way to do what you want to do, and there will (probably) be negligible performance loss that way. If performance is really a problem, try making sure that your /tmp directory is a RAM-based filesystem and putting your temporary files there. That way the temporary files are stored in RAM instead of on a hard drive, so reading/writing them is near-instant.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to ensure that you're writing whole lines in single write operations (so if you're using some form of stdio, you'll need to set it for line buffering for at least the length of the longest line that you can output.) Since the shell uses O_APPEND for the >> redirection then all your writes will then automatically append to the file with no further action on your part.

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, no. `>>` doesn't respect multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the idea of using temporary files, you could also use some kind of aggregating process, although you would still need to make sure your writes are atomic.

Think Apache2 with piped logging (with something like spread on the other end of the pipe if you're feeling ambitious). That's the approach it takes, with multiple threads/processes sharing a single logging process.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above it's quite a hack, but works pretty well =)

```
( ping stackoverflow.com & ping stackexchange.com & ping fogcreek.com ) | cat
```

same thing with '>>' :

```
( ping stackoverflow.com & ping stackexchange.com & ping fogcreek.com ) >> log
```

and with exec on the last one you save one process:

```
( ping stackoverflow.com & ping stackexchange.com & exec ping fogcreek.com ) | cat
```

Comment: In the original question, I specify that the lines of text in the output must remain intact (i.e., they shouldn't get mixed up with each other).  If two of the ping requests come back at exactly the same time, won't the lines in your example get "interleaved" (mixed up with each other)?  Some of the other answer suggest they will...

Comment: @conradlee I suspect this works *most* of the time because output of each ping is going into a pipe, which Linux guarantees no interleaving as long as each write is under the PIPE_BUF size (often 4 KB). It is not generally safe, though, since there is no guarantee each write by ping will be less than PIPE_BUF.